# How to bring up other views in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

OK. So after watching Jason Dolinger's best [introduction to MVVM](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650) video (which I recommend to anyone who's starting WPF. Over an hour of interesting stuff and I promise this one hour will bring you lots of good returns in the future), I'm now excited to implement it in my own project.

OK. So here's my MainWindow class, a XAML window that acts as the main MDI window of my project. I add a ViewModel for my window, ask my menu items to bind to ViewModel members instead of adding event handlers etc.

So far so good. Now I need to write the actual code in the command that is going to handle user's clicking a menu item. As soon as I go into the relevant command, I realize that neither my command nor the ViewModel have any reference to the actual View class, or other views/viewmodels.

So my question is, how do I load another view in response to execution of a command? Should it all go through the ViewModel, or should command objects have direct access to views? What's the standard practice here?

Comment: you need to change datacontext of main window. You add all your views and viewmodels in MainWindow.xaml and then you have your main window object in all views. So whenever you want to move from one view to another you change datacontext of MainWindow object to the new view.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez: That sounds like nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing this commands do is related to a view (no other logic) than the command can have a view, else split the command to 2 commands and compose them. it's ok to have ui commands, as long as they do not contain business logic related to your domain.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to end up adding a view (properly wired to its viewmodel) to some type of [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx). How exactly you do that is up to you.

The dirty solution would be to simply grab a reference to the panel from somewhere, create a view and viewmodel and add the view to the panel. This would work, but it would couple your command to lots of implementation details which is very undesirable.

To improve that state of affairs you need to start adding in suitable abstraction layers. It would be useful to see how different MVVM frameworks do this to get an idea about what might work well. For example, Prism uses the concept of [regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec10) to do this.